# How can I check if number is multiple of 3 or contains the digit 5?

Tags: python, if-statement, contains, modulo

```
digit = 5
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print ("MultipleOfThree", end=" ")
    elif i:
        for digit in str(i):
            print ("FiveInIt", end=" ")
    else:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

I want to see in one line like that:

```
1 2 MultipleOfThree 4 FiveInIt MultipleOfThree 7 8 MultipleOfThree 10 11 MultipleOfThree 12 13 14 FiveInIt ........
```

But the output gives:

```
FiveInIt FiveInIt MultipleOfThree FiveInIt FiveInIt MultipleOfThree .......
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
digit = 5
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print ("MultipleOfThree", end=" ")
    elif str(digit) in str(i):
        print ("FiveInIt", end=" ")
    else:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Comment: Minor comment: It needs to be `elif str(digit) in str(i):`

Comment: @DanielLenz Right! Thank you!

Comment: First, get the error of :
'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int

But when I tried str(digit) in str(i), it s okay

Thank you

Comment: @ÜmitYaman I fixed it thanks to DanielLenz's comment

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
digit = '5'
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print("MultipleOfThree", end=" ")
    elif digit in str(i):
        print("FiveInIt", end=" ")
    else:
        print(i, end=" ")
```